# How to start a chat client app on various platforms

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, messaging

Basically I'm trying to develop an App that sends some information (Text and Images) to a server and then this server redirects the info to a other devices.

What framework do you know to handle realtime communicaction between users?, I've checked Firebase (Firebase Cloud Messaging), and also I have checked frameworks like ionic to be able to develop once and then deploy in various platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Check out app warp - it pretty much has all the server code written for you already:

http://appwarp.shephertz.com/

It's mostly used for games, but you can easily use their services for IM.